# Where are my public / private GPG keys and how to share them (on Mac OS)?

Tags: mac, ssh, encryption, gnupg

I am using Mac OS with GnuPG (installed via Brew).

I run:

```
gpg --gen-key
```

enter my name and email address then it said that it generated a key pair.

Now, I have no idea where are the keys and how can I share the public key to my partner so they can encrypt their data. Then, afterwards how could I decrypt the data with my private key?

Please help.

Many thanks.

Comment: Look at first line of the output of `gpg --list-keys` command. And for exporting your public key you can look at the example at page: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-gnupg-export.html